# How to login to Gmail account in SWT browser?

Tags: java, browser, swt

I have an embedded SWT browser in my  Java application.I want to directly login to my gmail account in this browser given username and password .I dont want to see the login page in the browser and i want to go directly to the mail.Is this possible?What do i set the URL to?Is it possible by taking help of javascript?

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;


public class Dummy2 {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Browser b= new Browser(shell,SWT.NONE);

        b.setUrl("www.Gmail.com");
        //b.setText("<html><body> Helllooooooooooooo </body></html>");

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            //while (BGTrayApp.isOpen) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                    display.sleep();
            }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this by myself, but probably adding an authentication listener is the way to go:
[SWT Browser help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html#addAuthenticationListener(org.eclipse.swt.browser.AuthenticationListener))

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is possible, and it's certainly not advisable. Google likely has protections built-in to prevent this, as it can make it easier to conduct man-in-the-middle attacks. Also, how do you handle accounts that have two-factor auth (Google Authenticator) enabled? In these cases, you're asked for a token after the login form has been submitted.

Why do you need to do this? Have you considered any alternatives?