# SWT Browser - Google account login

Tags: java, browser, swt

I wanted to add a browser in my java(SWT framework) application.
The browser will show the content of URLs.
I have implemented it using [org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2Fpackage-summary.html).
Everything was working fine. But one URL has an option login with google account. When the user
clicked the login with the google account button it's opened a new IE window. After successful login, nothing is happening.
But when I tried the same URL in  Chrome/IE/Firefox browser. After successful login, it's redirected to another URL.

Have anyone faced this problem before. How can I get the redirected URL in org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser after successful login Like Chrome/IE/Firefox?

Code:

```
  Browser browser = new Browser(this, SWT.NONE);
     browser.setBounds(x, y, width, height));
     browser.setUrl(INITIAL_URL);

 browser.addLocationListener(new LocationListener(){
            public void changed(LocationEvent e){
                System.out.println("URL changed to : " + e.location);

                if (e.location.startsWith("https://**************")) {
                    e.doit = true;
                }

                if (e.location.contains("*******")) {
                    browser.setVisible(false);

                    Application.getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> {
                        //Get page content and parse it
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void changing(LocationEvent event) {
                // Redirected if needed
            }
        });
```

I got a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403393/how-to-login-to-gmail-account-in-swt-browser) but it's doesn't help me